# Why do I need to explicitly add os.getcwd() to sys.path when importing Python scripts from a C application?

Tags: python, c, python-embedding

I was going through the Python documentation regarding [Extending Python with C/C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html), and I found a very interesting scenario.  Consider that I have the following, trivial Python script named `test_script.py` in my working directory:

```
import time
def My_Python_Func():
    print "My_Python_Func() Called: " + str(time.time())
```

In the same directory, I have a file called `another_test_script.py`, which has:

```
import test_script
test_script.My_Python_Func()
```

Which works fine, when called as `python ./another_test_script.py`.  Now, I'm trying to call said function from a C environment linked with the Python libraries as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pVal;

int main()
{
    const char* script_name = "test_script";
    const char* func_name   = "My_Python_Func";

    Py_Initialize();

    pName = PyString_FromString(script_name);

    PyRun_SimpleString("import os");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    /* * * * IF I COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE OUT, pModule IS ALWAYS SET TO NULL * * * */
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    Py_DECREF(pName);
    if (pModule != NULL)
    {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, func_name);
    }
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, func_name);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        Py_DECREF(pName);
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

As noted in the comments in the above C program, commenting out the line containing `PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())")` causes the call to `PyImport_Import` to fail (returning `NULL`).  Furthermore, calling `PyRun_SimpleString("import test_script")` appears to behave the same way.

Why do  I need to manually add the current working directory to Python's `sys.path` list of strings, when simply importing it from another Python script in the same working directory?  Furthermore, why does Python not search the current working directory in the first place (as `os.getcwd()` returns the correct path)?  Is this an appropriate solution, if I wish to import functions from scripts bundled with my C application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the script directory to `sys.path` is a peculiarity of the `python` executable; it is not done by default when the interpreter is initialized, since it is not always appropriate to do so in embedded applications.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  Is this done primarily to prevent script names from interfering with the Python library itself?  Is this the proper method of calling Python functions from my C program (in which I assume the scripts are in the current working directory)?

Comment: Sorry if my question was a bit ambiguous, I'm experimenting with Python scripting instead of using Lua (which my application currently utilizes).  While the API's have some similarities, the import mechanisms are somewhat different, so I'm trying determine which is the best right now for me.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  I'll do some more digging in the API documentation... Thank you so much for your help!  Looking forward to using Python in my applications going onwards...

Comment: Some of the C API unfortunately isn't well documented; don't be afraid to dig around in the header files (and source if necessary) for useful stuff.